# how can fix Defective SoLoader version message from google play?

Tags: android, android-studio, google-play

when I try to upload my android version to google App Store I get this message "Defective SoLoader version
Your app uses a defective version of the SoLoader SDK, which can cause your app to crash. Update to a fixed version of SoLoader.", knowing that I do not use this library in my application can any one till me what should I do, thank you.

[image: image of google play message]

Comment: Contact google play support. We can't help you with a problem with their platform.

Comment: are you fix this issue?

Comment: https://support.google.com/faqs/answer/12576726